# How to emulate a drum sound?

Tags: fourier-analysis

I've been working in a personal project which the goal is to create a digital drum.
During my conjectures, I was thinking what is the best way to simulate the sound, below I will explain a simple idea that I had. If someone can show me a better way I appreciate.

The first thing I want to make it clear: I don't want to use recorded sounds, I will have some sensors of pressure in a pad and the idea is to create a sound proportional to the pressure applied to it.

My main idea is taking some samples on the Internet of different parts of a drum, make a Fourier analysis and save the magnitude and phase of each frequency that compounds the original sound.

$$
 Sound(t) \xrightarrow{\mathscr{F}} Sound(f)
$$

When a pressure is applied in my mechanical system, the sound will be recreated through inverse Fourier transformation and will be multiplied by an exponential term, with negative decay.
$$
 Sound(f) \xrightarrow{\mathscr{F}^-1} Sound(t)
$$

$$
ReconstructedSound = Sound(t).e^{-t/\alpha}
$$

The $\alpha$ term would be proportional to the pressure applied on the pads. More intense pressure would create louder and longer sound, while less intense would do the opposite effect.

Does it make sense this idea?

Does exist a more simple way?

Comment: It sounds like a reasonable *starting place*. But I can almost guarantee that you will find the initial results disappointing. You are not likely to find the expertise to fix that in this forum. the Physics Stack Exchange will serve you better, but there are probably better choices than them as well. You need to look for Acoustical engineering.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will post the question in physics exchange and look for acoustical engineering